# how to use aws public ips with elixir

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, routes, elixir

Have 2 iex shells running on different servers in EC2 but when I try to connect from one to the other I get this error:

```
Node.connect :them@ip-172-30-<--snip-->
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
:erlang
```

It looks like elixir doesn't like that the hostname has dashes in it. How can I change the hostname without breaking the routing between the EC2 instances?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by `atom literal` can not contain dash.
You can try `:a-b-c` and `:"a-b-c"` in iex.

So you should use `Node.connect :"them@ip-172-30-<--snip-->"`.

---

Besides, you can use `--name NAME` instead of `--sname NAME` to name a node.

`sname` option makes and assigns a short name with your hostname.

You can name the node with `--name` like `iex --name "them@thisismyhost`.

Comment: I don’t think thats valid elixir syntax. Shouldn’t it be `:"them@ip-172-30-<--snip-->"`?

Comment: Thanks! I needed to quote the hostname with dashes.